# How do i upload a icon to my app/xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

i have created a icon in photoshop and its a png file i have made a 57X57 pixels and a 114X114 pixels but when i insert it in my app in the simulater it has a black edge around it and i just want it to look like this

[image: this is it in photoshop]

it is a .psd file in this pick but the over version look the same but i saved them as .png 
here is the layer tab and my icon in Xcode 4.2 and in the simulater

[image: layer panel]

[image: icons in xcode 4.2]

[image: simulater]

thanks

Comment: @Jim is right.You should not add rounded corners yourself in it. Apple will do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your icon isn't 57x57 square, you've made it smaller to add a drop shadow and rounded corners.  You aren't supposed to do that, iOS does it for you.  See [Application Icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2) in the HIG.

Answer (score 0):

your icon isn't full 57 x 57 pixels.. it has gap on all sides (which is i think is filled with semi transparent color..check again in your psd).. which is getting filled with black color of the background... . stretch your icon to the sides..